# Hibernate envers is not updating the revision_field_name column causing a database exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a spring application that uses Hibernate Envers (latest version) to update the underlying table.
The problem is that for some reason Hibernate Envers is not incrementing the revision_field_name column, causing a database exception because the primary key of the table is a combination of a classic int id(NOT INCREMENTAL) and this column.
So the first time it inserts 1 - 1 and the second time it tries to insert the same numbers (1 - 1) causing the database error.

Here is the relevant code.

spring-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.service.springjpa"/>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.bar.domain"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

                <!-- Properties for Hibernate Envers -->
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_H</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">ACTION_TYPE</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp">True</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="foo.bar.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAwareBean"/>

    <bean id="auditorAwareBean" class="foo.bar.springjpa.auditor.AuditorAwareBean"/>
</beans>
```

ContactAudit.java :

```
package foo.bar.domain;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.envers.NotAudited;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;


@Audited
@Table(name = "CONTACT_AUDIT")
@Entity
public class ContactAudit implements Auditable<String, Long>, Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private int version;

    private Set<Hobby> hobbies = new HashSet<Hobby>();
    private Set<ContactTelDetail> contactTelDetails = new HashSet<ContactTelDetail>();

    //Audit fields
    private String createdBy;
    private DateTime createdDate;
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

    //constructors
    public ContactAudit() {
    }

    public ContactAudit(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public ContactAudit(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate, Set<Hobby> hobbies, Set<ContactTelDetail> contactTelDetails) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
        this.contactTelDetails = contactTelDetails;
    }

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        if (id == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    @Version
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @NotAudited
    @JoinTable(name = "contact_hobby_detail",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "HOBBY_ID"))
    public Set<Hobby> getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(Set<Hobby> hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotAudited
    public Set<ContactTelDetail> getContactTelDetails() {
        return contactTelDetails;
    }

    public void setContactTelDetails(Set<ContactTelDetail> contactTelDetails) {
        this.contactTelDetails = contactTelDetails;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_BY")
    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    //other methods
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Contact - Id: " + id + ", First name: " + firstName + ", Last name: " + lastName + ", Birthday: " + birthDate
                + ", Create by: " + createdBy + ", Create date: " + createdDate + ", Modified by: " + lastModifiedBy + ", Modifed date: " + lastModifiedDate;

    }

}
```

ContactAuditServiceImpl.java :

```
package foo.bar.service.springjpa;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import foo.bar.domain.ContactAudit;
import foo.bar.repository.ContactAuditRepository;
import foo.bar.service.ContactAuditService;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;


@Service("contactAuditService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ContactAuditServiceImpl implements ContactAuditService{

    @Autowired
    private ContactAuditRepository contactAuditRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ContactAudit> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(contactAuditRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ContactAudit findById(Long id) {
        return contactAuditRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ContactAudit save(ContactAudit contact) {
        return contactAuditRepository.save(contact);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ContactAudit findAuditByRevision(Long id, int revision) {
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        return auditReader.find(ContactAudit.class, id, revision);
    }
}
```

AuditorAwareBean.java

```
package foo.bar.springjpa.auditor;

import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;

public class AuditorAwareBean implements AuditorAware<String>{
    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        return "prospring3";
    }
}
```

Starting point of the application.
SpringJpaAuditSample.java :

```
package foo.bar;

import foo.bar.domain.ContactAudit;
import foo.bar.service.ContactAuditService;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class SpringJpaAuditSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        ContactAuditService contactService = ctx.getBean("contactAuditService", ContactAuditService.class);

        List<ContactAudit> contacts = contactService.findAll();
        listContacts(contacts);

        //Add new contact
        System.out.println("Add new contact");
        ContactAudit contact = new ContactAudit();
        contact.setFirstName("Michael");
        contact.setLastName("Jackson");
        contact.setBirthDate(new Date());
        contactService.save(contact);
        contacts = contactService.findAll();
        listContacts(contacts);

        //Update contact
        System.out.println("Update contact");
        contact.setFirstName("Tom");
        contactService.save(contact);
        contacts = contactService.findAll();
        listContacts(contacts);

        //Find audit record by revision
        ContactAudit oldContact = contactService.findAuditByRevision(1L, 1);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Old Contact with id 1 and rev 1:" + oldContact);;
        System.out.println("");
        oldContact = contactService.findAuditByRevision(1L, 2);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Old Contact with id 1 and rev 2:" + oldContact);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private static void listContacts(List<ContactAudit> contacts)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Listing contacts without details:");
        for(ContactAudit contact: contacts)
        {
            System.out.println(contact);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And of course the error I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not perform addBatch; SQL [insert into CONTACT_AUDIT_H (ACTION_TYPE, AUDIT_REVISION_END, AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS, BIRTH_DATE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_MODIFIED_BY, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, LAST_NAME, ID, AUDIT_REVISION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not perform addBatch
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:105)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy39.save(Unknown Source)
    at foo.bar.SpringJpaAuditSample.main(SpringJpaAuditSample.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not perform addBatch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy.autoFlushIfRequired(ValidityAuditStrategy.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy.perform(ValidityAuditStrategy.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.work.AbstractAuditWorkUnit.perform(AbstractAuditWorkUnit.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:666)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
    ... 38 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Update 1 : Database table script

```
CREATE TABLE CONTACT_AUDIT_H (
       ID INT NOT NULL
     , FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
     , LAST_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
     , BIRTH_DATE DATE
     , VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
     , CREATED_BY VARCHAR(20)
     , CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP
     , LAST_MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(20)
     , LAST_MODIFIED_DATE TIMESTAMP
     , AUDIT_REVISION INT NOT NULL
     , ACTION_TYPE INT
     , AUDIT_REVISION_END INT
     , AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS TIMESTAMP
     , UNIQUE UQ_CONTACT_AUDIT_H_1 (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
     , PRIMARY KEY (ID, AUDIT_REVISION)
);
```

Update 2 : My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleProject25</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SimpleProject25</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom revision entity? How are revision numbers generated? Is the revision number in the revision entity auto-incremented?

Comment: No, I am reading pro spring 3 book and there is no such entity.

Comment: @adamw : I think I've left a message at your blog. Why do you believe that nobody answers to this?(here and at the hibernate official forum).

Comment: How is reading a book about spring relevant here? :)

Comment: And where did you leave a message? At my blog, or at the hibernate forum? I usually answer all questions.

Comment: @adamw :This code comes from reading the book 'pro spring 3'. I think I left the message at you blog.

Comment: @adamw : I see in your bio that you are the project lead for hibernate envers. So I believe you can understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything on my blog. Anyway blog isn't the right place to ask such questions I guess :). Even though I am the project lead for Envers, I have no idea why this is happening. That's why I wanted to get some more info, like how are revision numbers generated (what is the generator), and is the rev number auto-incremented.

Comment: I have provided the class that gets the Audited annotation, the spring config file that creates the CONTACT_AUDIT_H table along with the underlying sql script.What else should I provide?

Comment: You can join hibernate-envers chat room , so that we don't clutter any more this post.

Comment: I've posted the sql code that mysql server gets from the application in the official hibernate forum (https://community.jboss.org/thread/228698)

Comment: As you can see I am not using a custom revision entity, I am just relying on Hibernate Envers' own internal entity as described here : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog

Comment: If you check carefully the sql code that arrives at mysql server , you'll see that AUDIT_REVISION number is not incremented by hibernate envers but stays the same.